# MySql PDO update query is not working, any idea why?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently trying to create a query that updates user's profile image.

Here's the code I am using to update the table:

```
$query = $connection->prepare("UPDATE userProfile SET profileImage = ? WHERE user = ? ");
$query->bindParam(1, $imageName);
$query->bindParam(2, $user);
$query->execute;
```

The connection to the database is not the problem, I have other queries working just fine. I may have glanced over my mistake in this problem but for some reason I just can't find it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo I'm sure

Comment: With no further context, and assuming `$connection` is a valid database connection, there’s nothing in there that shouldn’t work, as far as I can tell. What does `execute()` return—true or false? And have you looked in your MySQL logs to see what the actual query executed was?

Comment: Where are $user and $imageName defined?